# Tomcat access logging through log4j2?

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j2, access-log, tomcat-valve

I'm trying to have my own configuration for access logging with log4j2 logging framework in my web application that is using tomcat.
While I see there is a Access log valve that can be used for logback, I didn't find any access log valve to override for log4j2 framework at all.

Tomcat version: 9

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

Quoting directly from http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-appserver/index.html. Note that most of the steps below are designed to keep the log4j overrides separate from the standard tomcat stuff.

> Log4j may be used as the logging framework for Apache Tomcat. This support is implemented automatically by including the log4j-api, log4j-core, and log4j-appserver jars in the boot classpath. A file named log4j2-tomcat.xml, log4j2-tomcat.json, log4j2-tomcat.yaml, log4j2-tomcat.yml, or log4j2-tomcat.properties must also be placed in the boot classpath. This is most easily done by:
>
> 1. Creating a set of directories in catalina home named log4j2/lib and
>      log4j2/conf.
> 2. Placing log4j2-api-2.13.0.jar, log4j2-core-2.13.0.jar,
>      and log4j2-appserver-2.13.0.jar in the log4j2/lib directory.
> 3. Creating a file named log4j2-tomcat.xml, log4j2-tomcat.json,
>      log4j2-tomcat.yaml, log4j2-tomcat.yml, or log4j2-tomcat.properties in
>      the log4j2/conf directory.
> 4. Create or modify setenv.sh in the tomcat bin directory to include
>      CLASSPATH=$CATALINA_HOME/log4j2/lib/*:$CATALINA_HOME/log4j2/conf